# TFRecord encoding nested objects

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow and I am attempting to break up a large dataset into TFRecords. The format that I am encoding looks like this:

- ID(String, bytes)
- Index(int64)
- Time (int64)
- Image (Image, bytes)
- Label (List of Label, bytes)

A Label object has FrameID(int64), Category(int64), x1(Float), x2(Float), y1(Float), y2(Float)
However, I am struggling to get these information to be serialized. I broke up the List of Labels into Lists corresponding to their properties of the object (i.e, id[], category[] ...).

Currently, this is how individual elements are being serialized, adopted from TFRecord's document page:

```
def _bytes_feature(value):
  """Returns a bytes_list from a string / byte."""
  if isinstance(value, type(tf.constant(0))):
    value = value.numpy() # BytesList won't unpack a string from an EagerTensor.
  return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

def _float_feature(value):
  """Returns a float_list from a float / double."""
  return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[value]))

def _float_list_feature(value):
  return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=value))

def _int64_feature(value):
  """Returns an int64_list from a bool / enum / int / uint."""
  return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))

def _int64_list_feature(value):
  return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=value))
```

And this is how the data is being written into a tfrecords file.

```
def serialize_header(feature0, feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4, feature5, feature6, feature7, feature8, feature9):
    """
    Creates a tf.train.Example message ready to be written to a file.
    """
    # Create a dictionary mapping the feature name to the tf.train.Example-compatible data type.
    feature = {
        'id': _bytes_feature(feature0),
        'index': _int64_feature(feature1),
        'time': _int64_feature(feature2),
        'image': _bytes_feature(feature3),
        'frame_id': _int64_list_feature(feature4),
        'category': _int64_list_feature(feature5),
        'x1': _float_list_feature(feature6),
        'x2': _float_list_feature(feature7),
        'y1': _float_list_feature(feature8),
        'y2': _float_list_feature(feature9)
    }
    # Create a Features message using tf.train.Example.
    example_proto = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
    return example_proto.SerializeToString()

with tf.io.TFRecordWriter('test.tfrecords') as writer:
   result = serialize_header(b'TestID', 3, 4, open("b1c66a42-6f7d68ca.jpg", 'rb').read(), [3, 4], [1,2], [2.2, 3.3], [4.4, 5.5], [6.6, 7.7], [8.8, 9.9])
   print(result)
   writer.write(result)
```

So far things are doing well. Until when I attempt to read from the dataset is where I get stuck with an error.

```
raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('test.tfrecords')

# Create a dictionary describing the features.
feature_description = {
    'id': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    'index': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'time': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'image': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    'frame_id': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'category': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'x1': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
    'x2': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
    'y1': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
    'y2': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32)
}

def _parse_function(example_proto):
  # Parse the input tf.train.Example proto using the dictionary above.
  return tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, feature_description)

parsed_dataset = raw_dataset.map(_parse_function)
print(parsed_dataset)

for image_features in parsed_dataset:
  image_raw = image_features['id'].numpy()
  display(Image(data=image_raw))
```

Where the error is:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-c5d6610d5b7f> in <module>()
     49 print(parsed_dataset)
     50 
---> 51 for image_features in parsed_dataset:
     52   image_raw = image_features['id'].numpy()
     53   display(Image(data=image_raw))
InvalidArgumentError: Key: y2.  Can't parse serialized Example.
     [[{{node ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExampleV2}}]]
```

I can't determine whether am I encoding the data correctly, but decoding it wrongly, vice versa, or both. It would be great to have someone's expertise on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When created using `_int64_list_feature` / `_float_list_feature` Instead of `FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64/tf.float32)` try `tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.int64/tf.float32)`

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @bernardlee99 Please upvote and accept as answer then